# How to check all check-boxes one by one in selenium web driver with the java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using the below code , The test case is not failing but the code is not checking the check-boxes.

```
@Test(priority=11)
public void Test_CheckBox_Check()throws InterruptedException {

    List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//md-checkbox[@aria-checked='false']"));
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(els.size()));
    for ( WebElement el : els ) {

        el.click();

    }
}
```

[image: Test Case is not failing]
[image: Xptha and the elements]

[image]

Comment: Can you expand the div above the one currently expanded in the screenshot? One with the class value - 'md-container md-ink-ripple'. I think the checkbox is inside this div.

Comment: Please have a look the updated screen shot.

Comment: Can you try to click on this div instead or the one inside this? Not totally sure but I think it should work.

Comment: List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//md-checkbox/div")); But still showing 0 count :(.

Comment: Check if you need some kind of wait for these elements to be visible. Seems you are able to get them in the xpath checker in the browser. Can you run the latest xpath with the inner div in the browser and check what comes up.

Comment: its finding 35 results with the inner div path. //md-checkbox/div/div[@class="md-icon"]

Comment: After adding 2 seconds wait       Thread.sleep(2000);
 its working.   its  Cooooool - Thanxxxxx.

Comment: Is it showing just the checkbox? Try with an explicit wait on the visibility of these elements before you locate them.

Comment: Thanks #Grasshopper  :)

Comment: Do not use sleep. Use the explicit wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locator you are using might be the causing the issue try with below:

```
//div[@class='ng-scope flex-20']//following::md-checkbox**[@role='checkbox']**
```

You may omit the part in asterisk if all the elements that are identified by md-checkbox are checkboxes.

Below code worked for me in another case:

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='control-group']//following::input[@type='checkbox']"));
        for(WebElement check:checkboxes){
            check.click();
        }
```

Comment: FAILED: Test_CheckBox_Check
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //div[@class='ng-scope flex-20']//following::md-checkbox**[@role='checkbox']** is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class='ng-scope flex-20']//following::md-checkbox**[@role='checkbox']** because of the following error:
TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Comment: Above exception is coming now. Please have a look and help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

After adding some wait its working

```
@Test(priority=11)
public void Test_CheckBox_Check()throws InterruptedException {

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//md-checkbox/div/div[@class='md-icon']"));
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(els.size()));
    for ( WebElement el : els ) {

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        el.click();

         System.out.println(el.getText());
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-xs-1']")).click();

    }
```